# Two commands shown for 1 command?

Tags: discord, discord.js

**Details of my problem**

[image: Two ping commands]

I am currently following the discord.js v14 guide: https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin

Using deploy-commands.js to deploy my commands to my servers. This strange issue has occurred. It shows two ping commands (and for any other command it also shows to of them) to the user.

**What I was expecting**

A normal looking 1 command per 1 command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not duplicates! What you actually have is a global command and a guild command deployed with the same name. Remove either the global command or the guild command:

- Resetting global commands: `rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(clientId), { body: [] });`
- Resetting guild commands: `rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: [] });`